# How to ls -l file from output of grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep, ls

I was trying to run the following command:

```
ls -lh `grep -E "^log4j.appender.File" /var/domains/*/servers/*/logs/log4j.properties | sed 's/.*=//g'`
```

but it shows me error:

```
ls: cannot access /var/app/application.log: No such file or directory
```

But when I try to ls the output of the grep it is ok:

```
root> ls -l /var/app/application.log   
-rw-rw-r-- 1 application bea 289501889 Dec 2 18:05 /var/app/application.log
```

I am using bash script to list the file, if it doesn't exist my script will return error message. If exists I want to check the size, date and permissions.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the backtick with `$(grep .... etc)`? I heard that the backtick can cause problems.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that already and No such file or directory.

Comment: ...even with `""` , I mean `ls -lh "$(grep .... )" `?  If there are spaces or _strange_ characters (`\n` tabs) it can incur in problems. BTW  check the whole output of your `grep|sed` command to see if there is some problem maybe before the _offending line_.

Comment: Nope. I checked different system and it is working fine. I've compared the both properties files and it is identical. Strange.

Comment: You're running both the versions of `ls` as the same user, right?  If not does the user with the `grep` in it have permission to access the directories in the path?

Comment: @EricRenouf, yes, I use on both system root account. Yes user has permission to access the directory.

Also, I found this is issue with my session to this system. On one I use grep and it is ok, on different it will show me something like this:

`root> grep -E "^log4j......`
`root> pp/applicaiton.log`

the second line appears automatically. Tried to increase `stty cols` but it will not help.

Comment: Could you perhaps edit the question to include the output of just the `grep` command?  If possible do it with copy and paste so any unexpected or special characters will be preserved

Comment: Try this : `eval $(echo "\$( ls -lh $(grep -E "^log4j.appender.File" /var/domains/*/servers/*/logs/log4j.properties | sed 's/.*=//g'))")`

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the help. I found that at the end of line is not \n but \r. I didn't realized that so I add  `| tr -d '\r'` and it is working correctly.